# how to turn on the vibratiton when moving icons?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I just got my replacement Samsung Galaxy 3 phone, and every time I moved my icons around my phone would slightly vibrate but now after I made some changes to the settings I lost that feature. It's been driving me crazy trying to get it back.please help!

I've gone to the sound settings and turned the haptic feature on and off and still no changes to my phone.

Comment: Are you using a third party launcher? What version of Android? Stock or cutom ROM?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the settings for the launcher? Many launchers have this option in their settings menu. Go to your home screen, press menu and choose Settings. Look there for a vibrate or haptic feedback option.